# What is the best way to post a replay to YouTube?

Tags: starcraft-2

Since the starcraft2 replays are in their own replay format, but I think the SC 2 replays are pretty well watched on youtube, whats the best way using a camtasia like software to record the entire game?

Comment: Should this be a duplicate of: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5451/anyone-know-the-tools-process-used-by-starcraft-2-commentators-to-create-the-scre or the other way around?

Answer (score 8):

FRAPS -- records video and audio, shows a frame-rate couter. FRAPS itself is pretty lightweight, but the process of recording is pretty system-intensive: be sure you've got a decent PC before attempting this. 
http://www.fraps.com/

Comment: FRAPS is quite good - I used it a few times in a previous life for WoW PvP captures :)

Comment: I concur wholeheartedly with the FRAPS recommendation. I bought GameCam because it was cheap, and while it did the job, and got a decent resolution, it had what seemed to be an upper limit of 15 FPS on videos. Made for too choppy of videos for my liking. I switched to FRAPS and it has worked extremely well since.